# JPA Hibernate Fetch Collection for size retrievement

Tags: java, performance, hibernate, jpa

Is there any possibility to fetch a collection of an entity just for the retrievement of the size of it?

Something like:

```
FROM Cat c JOIN SIZE c.kittens
```

So I can use the result of a query like:

```
int sum = 0;

for(Cat c : em.createQuery("..", Cat.class).getResultList())
  sum += c.getKittens().size();
```

Is there any keyword or other possibility to get only the size.

It is not a big problem to fetch the whole collection for that purpose but I was just thinking of performance improvements and asked myself how this could be done?

Answer (score 2):

You can use SQL aggregate functions in JPQL
for single Cat

```
select count(*) from Kittens k where k.cat = :cat
```

For every Cat at once (all rows in Kittens table)

```
select count(*) from Kittens k
```

and retrieve it as

```
Long size = (Long) query.getSingleResult();
```

Comment: `COUNT` would only give the amount not the sum, using `SUM` gives the desired result without a loop.

Comment: @DrColossos - the OP is looking for the count, not the sum.

Comment: I think `SUM` is for arithmetic addition (3 + 8) like get total amount of money in account table. Whereas `COUNT` is count of the rows in a table.

Comment: @viktor hmmm, he's getting the size of the kittens and adds it to the overall amount (`sum +=`). Not quite sure though.

Comment: `getKittens()` should return some `Collection` therefore `size()` returns number of Kittens (rows). If you take count of rows in Kittens table you have sum of all Kittens from all Cats - assuming only Cat can have Kittens ;-)

Comment: @viktor I know how to write a query to retrieve the expected sum, but I asked if there was any possibility to retrieve an object with the number of children without fetching them directly. Something like this would probably do the job, but I wanted something like a keyword or workaround for this: SELECT new Cat(c.id, new my.package.MySet(count(c.kittens))) FROM Cat c